# Is there a difference between KeywordsFilterData and OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData when used with a Category?

Tags: 2011, core-service

I have written code to retrieve the keywords in a category. In one version I am calling `GetListXml` with a `KeywordsFilterData` and in another version I use `OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData`. The output from the two appears identical, which seems reasonable, but it's odd that there should be two ways of expressing this. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData` can filter on any of the items in an Organizational Item, more of a generic type of filter, where `KeywordsFilterData` is specifically only for Keywords.

Technically a Category can contain child Categories (not possible in the UI, but it is possible in the API). So with a `OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData` you could get the child Categories and the Keywords in your `GetListXml` call.

Comment: Thanks Bart. So in my use-case of just wanting a list of keywords, `KeywordsFilterData` is more correct... just in case there were child categories.

Comment: I'd say so indeed